# Is it meaningful to monitor physical memory usage on AIX?

Tags: aix

Due to AIX's special memory-using algorithm, is it meaning to monitor the physical memory usage in order to find out the memory bottleneck during performance tuning? 
   If not, then what kind of KPI am i supposed to keep eyes on so as to determine whether we need to enlarge the RAM capacity or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If a program requires more memory that is available as RAM, the OS will start swapping memory sections to disk as it sees fit. You'll need to monitor the output of vmstat and look for paging activity. I don't have access to an AIX machine now to illustrate with an example, but I recall the man page is pretty good at explaining what data is represented there.

Also, this looks to be a good writeup about another AIX specfic systems monitoring tool, and watching your systems overall memory (svgmon).

http://www.aixhealthcheck.com/blog.php?id=255

To track the size of your individual application instance(s), there are several options, with the most common being `ps`. Again, you'll have to check the man page to get information on which options to use. There are several columns for memory sz per process. You can compare those values to the overall memory that's available on your machine, and understand, by tracking over time, if your application is only increasing is memory, or if it releases memory when it is done with a task.

Finally, there's quite a body of information from IBM on performance tuning for AIX, but I was never able to find a road map guide to reading that information. A lot of it assumes you know facts and features that aren't explained in the current doc set, so you then have to try and find an explanation, which oftens leads to searching for yet another layer of explanations. ! :^/

IHTH.